# Not able to access Coldfusion Rest Service through website url - Coldfusion

Tags: rest, iis, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

My coldfusion version is 10 and configured with iis. I have configured Rest service using the following code

```
<cfset restInitApplication(getDirectoryFromPath(getCurrentTemplatePath()), "myservicename") />
```

My cfc which is in same directory looks something like that

```
component restpath="test" rest="true" produces="application/json"
{
     remote array function getResult(
        required string tmpID restargsource="path",
        string startDate restargsource="query",
        string endDate restargsource="query"
    )
            httpmethod="GET"
            restpath="{tmpID}"
    {
        return arguments.tmpID;
    }

}
```

I am trying to access the rest service by url but it is giving me 404 not found error. Here is url which i have tried.

```
http://localhost:8500/rest/myservicename/test/10221
http://example.com/rest/myservicename/test/10221
http://127.0.0.1/rest/myservicename/test/10221
```

But all three is not working for me. When i try to refresh the service from coldfusion administrator, it is giving me following error.

```
Unable to refresh REST service.
 Application myservicename could not be initialized.
 Reason: The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.
 The application does not contain any rest enabled CFCs.
```

I have save my cfc to webroot of iis and update the root path of rest service through coldfusion administrator. Then above error is gone and got the green message 'Server has been updated successfully'. But still not accessible through any url. Still getting 404 error. Can any one point me where i am doing wrong? Or help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: You are missing the `;` from the end of `return arguments.tmpID` could just be a simple syntax error causing the issue. BTW, have you looked at http://taffy.io/ ?

Comment: #John,oh! i missed while posting. I have already worked with taffy somehow. Not too much. This rest service is working on my old server. After updating the server, it is not working.